# How do I fix this error? (arduino casting)

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm using a library called DS3231 by rinkydinkelectronics
Link: http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/library.php?id=73 (click on manual)

i'm trying to run the following code

```
String alarmTime = "08:52:00";

        void loop(){
           if (rtc.getTimeStr() == alarmTime){
           alarmState = true;
          }
}
```

but i get the following error:

> exit status 1 no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'char*' and
>   'String')

the library manual however says that the return value is a string so I don't see why this shouldn't work :(

Can someone help me fix this or tell me what might be wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Wrap the return in `std::string (...)`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean sorry, I'm a little new at all of this
Could you show me what you mean?

Comment: I'll post an answer.  However please keep on practicing c++ coding...

Comment: Is the C++ standard library available?

Comment: @ArthurP.R. not on Arduinos. However there is a very stripped down version written by someone [here](http://andybrown.me.uk/2011/01/15/the-standard-template-library-stl-for-avr-with-c-streams/), although it uses quite a lot of the Arduino's memory (depending on which model it is, the MEGA should be fine)

Comment: Which string class is used? With standard c there isn't a string class

Comment: i use the UNO so that won't work

Comment: @ArthurP.R. Arduino has a [`String` class](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringLibrary)

Comment: `if (String(rtc.getTimeStr()) == alarmTime)` might work.

Comment: @RetiredNinja post that as an answer :P

Comment: Haha same thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understood your code right, you want to check whether both strings are equal. Because the standard library is not available in the Arduino IDE, you must choose a different way. Convert the C string (`char*`) to a [`String` object](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringLibrary).

Example:

```
if(String(rtc.getTimerStr()) == alarmTime) {
    ....
}
```

This should work.

Comment: when I declare alarmTime as:
std::String alarmTime = "08:52:00";

I get an error:
"'String' in namespace 'std' does not name a type"

Comment: Just tested it out and it works perfectly thank you so much!

Comment: Sure. Just keep coding! :3

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compare two different things with confusingly similar names. A [string](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/String)(C style string) is a null terminated char array. This is different from the [String object](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject). It's generally accepted that with extremely memory limited hardware such as the standard Arduino boards you should avoid the use of the String class if possible as it uses more memory and may cause memory fragmentation from dynamic memory allocation. Much better to use strings instead, which are actually pretty much just as easy to work with as String.

Your code using only strings:

```cpp
char alarmTime[] = "08:52:00";

void loop() {
  if (strcmp(rtc.getTimeStr(), alarmTime) == 0) {
    alarmState = true;
  }
}
```